# Need help in grails model association

Tags: grails, associations

I am facing problem with Grails model association. Here is problem:

- Subscriber and Customer are extended from PartyRole.
- A customer may have many subscribers and a subscriber belongs To customer.
- A Party may have many PartyRole.
- Person and Organization are extended from Party.
- A Person belong to Organization.
- A Person has many Profile and a profile belongs to Person.

Now I want to edit currently logged-in user(subscriber)  which is basically organization type mean has organization properties like orgName and orgSize.

I can find Person(firstName and lastName) and Profile (emails) details using logged-in user(subscriber) but not able to get Organization details. Code is following.

```
 def profile = {
    Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = Subscriber.get( springSecurityService.principal.id )
    if (loggedinSubscriber == null){
      redirect(controller: "login" , action:"login");
    }
    else{
      println loggedinSubscriber
      Party person = Person?.get(loggedinSubscriber.party.id)
      Party org = Organization?.get(loggedinSubscriber.party.id)
      Profile profile = person?.profile
      [userInstance: person, authorityList: sortedRoles()]
    }
  }
```

When I tried to get Organization details with

```
Party org = Organization?.get(loggedinSubscriber.party.id)
```

I got null value but in same way I can get Person details using logged-in user(subscriber) and both are extended from Party.`

Any idea to how to get Organization details.

**Person:**

```
package com.vproc.member

import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Notification;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;

class Person extends Party{

    String firstName
    String lastName

    Profile profile
    static belongsTo = [Organization]

    static constraints = {
        lastName nullable:true
        firstName blank:false

    }

}

**Organization:**

package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

class Organization extends Party{

    String orgName 
    Person contact
    int orgSize
    boolean isVendor 

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Profile:**

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;

class Profile {

    String emailAddress  //  field governed by privacy policy
    String phoneNumber   //  field governed by privacy policy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    boolean isDefaultProfile
  String status
    static belongsTo = [person:Person]
    //ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum privacyLevel = ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Subscriber:**

```
package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

import com.vproc.common.StatusEnum;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Discussion;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Enquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Membership;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Notification;
import com.vproc.enquiry.SharedEnquiry;
import com.vproc.enquiry.Team;
import com.vproc.order.Seat;

class Subscriber extends PartyRole{

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    StatusEnum status
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    List<Contact> contacts ;

    static belongsTo = [ customer: Customer]
    static hasMany = [seats: Seat, ownedEnquiries: Enquiry,enquiresSharedWith: SharedEnquiry, enquiriesSharedBy: SharedEnquiry ,
         managedTeams: Team , memberships: Membership, contacts: Contact , sharedByContacts: SharedContact, sharedWithContacts: SharedContact,
          vContacts: VContact, partOf: VContact,  sharedbyVContacts: SharedVcontact, sharedWithVcontacts: SharedVcontact,
          notifications: Notification, discussions: Discussion]
    static mappedBy = [ managedTeams : "manager" , enquiresSharedWith: "sharedWith" , enquiriesSharedBy: "sharedBy"  ,
                                                   sharedByContacts : "sharedBy" , sharedWithContacts : "sharedWith" ,
                                                   vContacts: "forSubscriber"  ,  partOf :"ofContact",
                                                   sharedbyVContacts: "sharedby" , sharedWithVcontacts :"sharedWith"
                                                    ]


    static constraints = {
        username  validator : { val , obj ->
                                 if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
                                        val!= null
                              }
        username unique: true
        password validator : { val , obj ->
                                    if (obj.status != StatusEnum.Pending)
                                        val != null
                             }

        contacts nullable: true
        notifications nullable : true
        username nullable: true
        password nullable: true

    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        SubscriberRole.findAllBySubscriber(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

**Party:**

package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

```
class Party {

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false 
    }
}
```

**PartyRole:**

package com.vproc.member

import java.util.Date;

```
class PartyRole {

    Party party

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false 
    }
}
```

**BootStrap:**

class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

```
def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
def guestRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_GUEST') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_GUEST').save(failOnError: true)
def csrRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_CSR') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_CSR').save(failOnError: true)

//PersonRole.create adminUser, adminRole
def address = new Address( city : 'Pune' , stateCode : 'MH' , countryCode : 'IN'   )

def adminProfile = Profile.findByEmailAddress('sachin.jha@gmail.com' )?: new Profile(
    privacyLevel: ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private,
    emailAddress:  "sachin.jha@gmail.com" ,
    phoneNumber: "9325507992",
    status : 'Active'
    ).save( failOnError: true)

 def adminPerson = Person.findByProfile( adminProfile) ?: new Person( firstName: 'admin' , lastName : 'user' , profile: adminProfile).save( failOnError: true) ;
 def vprocOrganization = Organization.findByOrgName('VPROCURE') ?: new Organization ( orgName: 'VPROCURE' , orgSize : 100 , mailingAddress: address, contact: adminPerson ).save( failOnError: true)
 def vprocCustomer = Customer.findByParty( vprocOrganization) ?: new Customer ( party: vprocOrganization, status: StatusEnum.Active  ).save(failOnError: true) ;
 def adminUser = Subscriber.findByUsername('admin') ?: new Subscriber( username : 'admin' ,  password : 'passw0rd' , enabled: true , party: adminPerson, customer: vprocCustomer , status: StatusEnum.Active ).save( failOnError: true)

 if ( !adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
      SubscriberRole.create adminUser, adminRole
    }

  JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
     return it?.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
  }

    def userProfile = Profile.findByEmailAddress( 'sachin.jha.user@gmail.com') ?: new Profile(
        privacyLevel: ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private,
        emailAddress: "sachin.jha.user@gmail.com",
        phoneNumber : "9325507992",
        status : 'Active'
        ).save( failOnError: true)

    def userPerson = Person.findByProfile( userProfile) ?: new Person( firstName: 'plain' , lastName : 'user' , profile: userProfile).save( failOnError: true) ;
    def plainUser = Subscriber.findByUsername('plainuser') ?: new Subscriber( username: 'plainuser', password : 'passw0rd' , enabled: true , party: userPerson, customer: vprocCustomer , status: StatusEnum.Active ).save( failOnError : true )
    if ( !plainUser.authorities.contains(userRole)){
        SubscriberRole.create  plainUser, userRole
    }

/*vprocCustomer.addToSubscribers(amdinUser)
vprocCustomer.addToSubscribers(plainUser)
vprocCustomer.save( failOnError : true);*/

}

def destroy = {
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your domain classes?

Comment: hi @Eylen, I have updated question with domain classes. Please have a look.

Comment: As far as I can understand... you're just associating a subscriber with just one Party, it's not possible to retrieve Person and Organization using the same id...
Also, if you're sure that you're retrieving the correct person instance (you'd better check it) you should be able to access person company easilly, just do person.company

Comment: hi @Eylen, for better understanding, I have added BootStrap.groovy file where Users have been created. As per your, what changes do I need to make to retrieve organization details in domain classes.

Comment: I think that you have two options, if the organization is the one associated with the Person, just access it with person.organization and it should work.
If it's another organization, you have to include another belongsTo in the PartyRole (you could just add Person and Organization to avoid problems)...
But if I've undertood well your problem, the first solution should do the trick.
Sorry for not adding code, but I don't have too much time right now...

Comment: hi @Eylen  Party org = person?.organization did not work and an error is No such property: organization for class: com.vproc.member.Person. Regarding ur second suggestion, do you mean that I should include belongsTo [Organization] in Subscriber domain ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39061/discussion-between-vieenay-and-eylen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change in Person domain class

```
static belongsTo = [Organization]
```

to

```
static belongsTo = [organization:Organization]
```

and access organization info from person instance with person.organization